# How to apply video processing on the GPU

Tags: image-processing, texture2d, sharpdx

I have a issue in programming for the graphics Card.
I write a shader for Image processing (I use DirectX 11 in combination with SharpDX), but the Transfer from the CPU to the GPU is really slow (sometime about 0.5 seconds), but I think there should be a faster way than using Texture2D.FromStream, because when playing a video, also every image of the Video has to be transfered to the GPU (or am I wrong at this Point?).
How can I Speed up this process?

Comment: Are you sending the results of each pixel individually? Or is the library doing some sort of update after each pixel?

Comment: I am sending a Texture2D to the graphics card, with the Texture2D.FromStream method of SharpDX.